# php results return empty

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying a connection to mysql and retrieve some information. The connection is successful, but produces a blank page. Below is the code. Appreciate help in checking what is wrong.

Thank you in advance
Richard

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
// include server parameters
require('includes/configure.php');

$con=mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_SERVER_USERNAME,DB_SERVER_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//$username = $_GET['username'];
//$password = $_GET['password'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Workshops");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$data = $row[0];

if($data){
    echo $data;
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please include your "configure.php" file... maybe blank out any sensitive information please?

Comment: Also is the first row blank on the table? Do you have any data in the table?

Comment: there is data in the table, the configure.php has the constants for the login

Comment: if you mean blank page as white page, it can be ERROR 500, try to enable error_reporting

Comment: define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost'); // eg, localhost - should not be empty for productive servers
  define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'username');
  define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', 'password');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'dbname');

Comment: it is not error 500, because when there is code error, it shows "error 500" how do we enable error_reporting?

Comment: as for first row, i tried $row[1]; still empty page

Comment: i tried adding  echo "test test"; but still ended up with an empty page

Comment: Error log, what is there?

Comment: Try 'var_dump($row)'. It will show you what is in the array, if anything. Great debugging tool.

Comment: ok, where do I find the error log? testing 'var_dump'

Comment: Hey guys, thanks a lot for helping, but doesn't seem to work, will go through the whole thing again step by step. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This should be in comment but I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I just post as answer.

You can try these checking:

1. Make sure your table name is correct
2. Instead of `$data = $row[0]`, try `$data = $row['your_columm_name']`. If you only want a single record, edit your query by adding WHERE clause.

Hope these help, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Before `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` 
add this lines to 'what you get from DB'

`echo "<pre>".var_dump($result)."</pre>";`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like mysqli_fetch_array has two categories i.e. numeric and associative array. Take a look at the example in the link. You can change your code as shown below.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row["yourtablecolumn"],$row["yourtablecolumn"]);
```

You can also use, mysqli_fetch_assoc($result).

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  

    $connection = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "root", "register"); //1. You have to change here
    if ($connection -> connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }


    $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'register'); //2. you have to change Database name
    if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Workshops`";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
        or die(mysql_error());

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $data = $row[0];
        if($data){
            echo $data;
    }
?>
```

[image]

Check with this code again rewrote & tested

**Note : I have marked the places where you should change according to your database configurations**

Open for any modifications

Comment: Try to creat a new php file & paste the code. Then just edit the connection detais & the database name itself in the same php code. And then run..  Im sure code is 100% working

Comment: Use `print_r($result);` below to the  `$result` it will show some hints & information about the variable at the moment